# python import not working in my production server only

Tags: python, python-import

Using Python 2.7.9 (both in prod and in localhost)
My past code was like so

```
from environment import *
```

I had an issue where I added some paths to `sys.path` and the import imported from another `environment.py` file which was not my app's.

So I want to be explicit about this import and changed to

```
from ApiService.environment import *
```

which worked in my localhost but not in production.

The directory structure is the same

```
ApiService/
   __init__.py 
   environment.py
   main.py
```

getting

```
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ApiService.environment import *
ImportError: No module named ApiService.environment
```

in my prod server only

i'm executing the app from the `ApiService` directory both in localhost and in prod

**edit**:

output of `echo -e 'import sys\nprint(sys.path)' | python`

in localhost

```
['', '/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python27.zip', '/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7', '/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

in production

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

`pwd` in both environments

localhost : `/Volumes/dev/Backend/ApiService`

production: `/apps/ApiService`

Comment: Are you using the same version of Python on the 2 machines?

Comment: How can we possibly answer this? We have no idea what your production environment is. Or your local environment. Or what the error is. This needs a [mcve].

Comment: What is running your code on your production machine?

Comment: are you sure that the ApiService folder is in your `PYTHONPATH` ?

Comment: do you have the __init__.py in the ApiService ?

Comment: it might be missing __ini__.py file?

Comment: it has a __init__.py file in the production server as well

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH is empty both in localhost and in prod

Comment: Python 2.7.9 on linux in prod and same on localhost

Comment: What if you `import ApiService`?

Comment: @ValentinLorentz `import ApiService`
`ImportError: No module named ApiService`

Comment: Could you please execute `echo -e 'import sys\nprint(sys.path)' | python` on both machines and show outputs?

Comment: @frist edited  my question

Comment: @WebQube what is the full path of your current directory (`pwd`) and the full path of `ApiService` directory on both machines?

Comment: @frist added in the question. but I don't see the relevance

Comment: @WebQube I mean what is the path (`pwd`) from where you start python console and `import ApiService` displays an exception

Comment: Shouldn't your working dir be one directory above `/Volumes/dev/Backend/ApiService`? If you are in `ApiService` dir, you can `import environment`, if in directory above, you can `import ApiService.environment`.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski my working directory is inside `ApiService` in both cases.

Comment: That shouldn't be working on your local system (given the `sys.path` and `pwd` results you've shown). Do you have `ApiService` installed anywhere else on that system? Perhaps it's getting imported from somewhere other than where you're running it. Perhaps you could print out `ApiService.__file__` (or `ApiService.environment.__file__`) to double check you're getting the one you expect?

Comment: I think some of parts `/Volumes/dev/Backend/ApiService` is a symlink into you home (`/Users/partuck`) directory or vice versa. Could you please execute `readlink -f /Volumes/dev/Backend/ApiService` and `readlink -f /Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib` on your local machine?

Comment: getting readlink: illegal option -- f

Comment: I don't know if it's a acceptable but you can add additional path (`/apps`) in `PYTHONPATH` environment while starting you application on production (`PYTHONPATH=/apps python ...py`). It's not very clear why does it work on your local machine.